# how to search git log with certain keyword_a but without keyword_b?

Tags: regex, git

How to search git log with ceratin keyword_a but without keyword_b?
Assume I have a branch master with 3 commits, the comments are t123, b1 and b12 separately.

```
* b90b03f (HEAD -> master) b12
* 27f7577 efb12g
* 7268b40 t123efgb12
* b90b03f b12efg
```

And now, I want to use `git log --grep <regex>` to search the log without ef and with log b12. The result I want is

```
b90b03f b12
```

Comment: The result you want is?

Comment: @Paolo My question has been wrongly reedited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the pattern `b` followed by two digits, you can use:

```
git log --grep 'b[0-9]\{2\}$'
```

Comment: What about the commit is changed and the question is more difficult?

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: See the edited question.  Maybe the former question misleads you.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. But I still have to look for the answer. What am I want to achieve is to search the log with the keyword "timer" and without "network".

Comment: I wrongly thought that the example in my question expresses such a situation.